# At what speed will a flat iron square of 10 sq meters fall at every second if dropped from a height of 10 meters?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

I've been trying to read the Wikipedia articles on drag, and picked up some books on physics to scan, but they're almost unreadable for me, the average person.

What are the equations for the speed and acceleration of a flat iron square, 2 cm thick and 10 sq meters in size, falling parallel to the ground will fall at every second, taking into account gravity and drag?

Comment: Do you mean per gravity effect only (the speed increases by 9.81 m/s per second), or taking into account aerodynamics (drag as you mentioned)? If the latter, then what is the thickness?

Comment: taking into account gravity + drag, thickness is 2 cm

Comment: Do you want to assume that the plate stays parallel to the ground? Intuitively, at least to me, it doesn't seem that would happen in the real world.

Comment: I'll do that then.

Comment: Added it as question there.

Comment: Um, I think the moderators are supposed to migrate it rather than double-post.

Answer (score 2):

I think you really do not need to care about aerodynamic drag in this particular case. The height of drop is so low and weight of the plate so heavy in relative terms that the plate would hit the ground long before you can say word DRAG. It would be a more interesting question had you been dropping the plate from a height of say 1000m. Then perhaps we might see the plate reaching terminal velocity before it huts the ground due to aero drag.

Comment: The event will take longer than you think.  Even with no drag, an object will only fall 4.9 meters in the first second.  It will take about 1.4 seconds to fall 10 meters.

Comment: Yes. I can calculate that. But obviously that time is not sufficient to demand consideration of drag for any practical purpose. For academic interest one can always calculate some numbers which may not be of much relevance in practice.